# State Monad mix IO and non-IO

Tags: haskell, monads

I tried to use State Monad for simple variables and it work. But here it seems that I am trying mix IO and non-IO.
The intention to have a array managed by the State Monad. I want to read and write to this array.

Seems harder than I thought.

```
        funarray :: Map.Map String (IOArray Int Int)
        funarray = Map.empty

        storearray :: String ->  (IOArray Int Int)-> State (Map.Map String  (IOArray Int Int)) ()
        storearray x value = do
        funarray <- get
        put (Map.insert x value funarray)

        retrievearray :: String -> State (Map.Map String  (IOArray Int Int)) (Maybe ( (IOArray Int Int)))
        retrievearray arr = do
        funarray <- get
        return (Map.lookup arr funarray)

        putmutablearray = do {
                   arr <- newArray (512,512) 0 ;
                   storearray "value-table" arr
                 }
        getmutablearray = do { retrievearray "value-table";}

        putthenget = do {putmutablearray; getmutablearray;}

        value :: BoardState -> IO Int
        value  (BoardState xloc oloc index) = do {
          arr <- (runState putthenget funarray);
          v <- (readArray arr index);
          return v
        }
```

Multiple errors starting with this.

```
* Couldn't match expected type `IOArray Int Int'
              with actual type `IO (IOArray Int Int)'
* In the second argument of `storearray', namely `createarray'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: storearray "value-table" createarray
  In the expression: do { storearray "value-table" createarray }
```

Can I mix them ?

This is just a global array. A large one. I need large ones for Machine Learning tasks.

Update : In an imperative language I would store this globally.

```
          createarray :: IO ( IOArray Int Int)
          createarray =  do {
                   arr <- newArray (512,512) 0;
                   return arr
              }
```

Comment: This feels a bit like you have a problem with the solution you came up with. Can you give us a bit more context of what you try to achieve?

Comment: Please be so kind and add signatures to all function definitions - so you can make sure your functions are as expected

Comment: It seems as if you want to both update the state in the state monad and perform IO access (to the array). You can't do that at the same time: either you work in state monad or in the IO one. If you want to do both, you have to pick a monad which allows both e.g. `StateT (IOArray ...) IO`, using monad transformers and `liftIO` to embed the IO actions. This requires some advanced understanding of monads, though. However, maybe what you need is much simpler than that. You should explain your task better: using state monad+IO arrays+IO+Map is a bit weird to see.

Comment: Maybe what you suggest is better. I just need a 'global' array which I can read and write to.

Comment: But it should be globally accessible. Multiple functions read and write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer. I think this is the idiomatic Haskell answer. Other experts can opine. Not sure how to make the array globally accessible though. I am told that isn't correct Haskell.

```
   type ArrayAccess = ReaderT  (IOArray Int Int)  IO 
   type ArrayWriteAccess = ReaderT  (IOArray Int Int)  IO() 

   readvalue ::  Int -> ArrayAccess Int   
   readvalue x    = do 
   a <- ask
   b <- liftIO( readArray a x);    
   return b

   writevalue ::  Int -> Int -> ArrayWriteAccess   
   writevalue x y   = do 
   a <- ask
   liftIO( writeArray a x y)    

   -- Test array accesses
   readfromarray = do { a <- createarray; liftIO (runReaderT (readvalue 1) a) }
   writetoarray = do { a <- createarray; liftIO (runReaderT (writevalue 1 2) a) }
```